# "N" before text in sql server

Tags: sql-server, function, triggers

I have a function

```
create Function [dbo].[persianNum]
(
@persionstr nvarchar(255)
)
Returns nvarchar(255)
 AS
Begin
Declare @out nvarchar(255)
-- code
 return @out
END
```

and I call this : 
" `select dbo.persianNum (N'۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۳:۵۵')`   "
this line Worked correctly.

now I wanted to call this in my trigger
 '`۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۳:۵۵`' is in `@myInput`

```
 select dbo.persianNum (@myinput)
```

but I need  " `N` " before my input
 How put it before the `@myinput`

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[persianNum]
(
@persionstr nvarchar(255)
)
Returns nvarchar(255)
--۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۴:۴۴ ۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۳:۵۵
AS
Begin
Declare @out nvarchar(255)
Declare @ss nvarchar(255)
Declare @persianTemp nvarchar(255)
Declare @len int

set @len = LEN(@persionstr)
   set @persianTemp= @persionstr
  set @out=''
while @len>0


Begin
set @len=@len-1;
 set @ss = SUBSTRING(@persianTemp, 1, 1)
set @persianTemp=SUBSTRING(@persianTemp, 2, @len)
set @out=@out+
CASE @ss
WHEN N'۰' THEN N'0'
WHEN N'۱' THEN N'1'
WHEN N'۲' THEN N'2'
WHEN N'۳' THEN N'3'
WHEN N'۴' THEN N'4'
WHEN N'۵' THEN N'5'
WHEN N'۶' THEN N'6'
WHEN N'۷' THEN N'7'
WHEN N'۸' THEN N'8'
WHEN N'۹' THEN N'9'

ELSE @ss
END


END       
     return @out
END
```

this is my complete function

Answer (score 2):

The N is used to cast as string as `NVARCHAR`, once a string is already an `NVARCHAR` you don't need to cast it again. You need to define `@myinput` as `NVARCHAR` otherwise your Persian text will not be encoded correctly.

Comment: Can you post the remainder of your code ? I can't reproduce your issue locally, there might be some additional code in `[dbo].[persianNum]` that is not handling the Persian input correctly.

Comment: I can not put "SET @myinput = N'۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۳:۵۵' " because myinput filled from a field in a table

Comment: Is that column defined as `NVARCHAR` ? You have to use `NVARCHAR` consistently. Once your string is converted to `VARCHAR` you will get ???????

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the N before @myinput. Instead place it where you set the value of your variable.

**Exampe**

```
SET @myinput = N'۰۸/۰۲/۲۰۱۶ ۱۰:۱۳:۵۵';
```